# after filing in the address information on one page checkout it redirects to the failure url i.e., back to the shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, redirect, store-view, onepage-checkout

i have magento 1.9 installed and when i checkout and try to register it directs me back to the shopping cart page the error log reads :
client denied by server configuration: public_html/skin/frontend/rwd/default/scss/ on onepagecheckout page

Comment: Did you check your server log and js error console?

Comment: yes i did it returns this error : client denied by server configuration: public_html/skin/frontend/rwd/default/scss/ on onepagecheckout page

Answer (score 1):

Thanks R.S. for pointing me to look up the js error console actually the problem was that my store runs on a temporary url and my antivirus was blocking the further steps (considering it a phishing url) so it kept redirecting me to the failure url in this case the shopping cart. Its solved now.